# linear model having 4 predictors

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a linear model having 4 predictors. The problem I am facing is my code doesn't estimate the one parameter. Every time when I put the one variable at last of my lm formula it doesn't estimate it. My code is:

```
AllData  <- read.csv("AllBandReflectance.csv",header = T)
Swir2ref <- AllData$band7 
x1 <- AllData$X1
x2 <- AllData$X2
y1 <- AllData$Y1
y2 <- AllData$Y2

linear.model <- lm( Swir2ref ~ x1 + y1 +x2 +y2 , data = AllData )
summary(linear.model)

Call:
lm(formula = Swir2ref ~ x1 + y1 + x2 + y2, data = AllData)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.027277 -0.008793 -0.000689  0.010085  0.035097 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.595593   0.002006 296.964   <2e-16 ***
x1          0.002175   0.003462   0.628    0.532    
y1          0.001498   0.003638   0.412    0.682    
x2          0.022671   0.018786   1.207    0.232    
y2                NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01437 on 67 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02876,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.01473 
F-statistic: 0.6613 on 3 and 67 DF,  p-value: 0.5787
```

Comment: There is a message there "(1 not defined because of singularities)" - you need to check what all your predictors look like. If one of your variables duplicates another predictor or is very highly correlated with others you will run into these issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem is exactly what you said.